# pages/forms/allitems.aspx missing from my sub site

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a subsite in sharepoint and I want to go to pages/forms/allitems.aspx. It is not there? Why would it be missing? I want to see what layout a page is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason why you will not have it is because that your subsite might be. Non-publishing template, like team site,blank site etc.only publishing site will have pages based on layout.

Answer (score 0):

To see what page layout is being used by a page

http:///_layouts/sitemanager.aspx?Source=%2Fdefault%2Easpx
navigate to the page you want to view the properties of
the page layout should be listed on the right hand column

I think its only sites with publishing enabled on them that have this though.

alternatively you could query the properties bag for the "PageLayout" property of each page to get the page layout programmatically